# Issue installing pip on Macosx ver 10.14.6 , using python3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.7

brew info python

```
python: stable 3.7.7 (bottled), HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: gdbm ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, readline ✔, sqlite ✘, xz ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
==> Analytics
install: 294,558 (30 days), 1,226,321 (90 days), 5,433,589 (365 days)
install-on-request: 203,226 (30 days), 688,138 (90 days), 2,779,676 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Cleanup all existing pip on machine

```
 sudo pip uninstall pip
```

No more pip now.

Installing pip , following instruction from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/.

My setup:

```
pyenv whence python
3.7.7
```

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Now trying to install pip using

```
python get-pip.py

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I added pip.conf file and set variable PIP_CONFIG_FILE point to the directory of pip.conf

```
pip.conf file  
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org
```

```
python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
Successfully installed pip-20.1 wheel-0.34.2
```

```
But it install it in /Users/<user>/.local/bin.

-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  250 May  7 18:45 pip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  250 May  7 18:45 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  250 May  7 18:45 pip3.7
```

```
<user>-mbp:python_others <user>$ ls -l /Users/<user>/.pyenv/shims/
total 168
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 2to3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 2to3-3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 easy_install-3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 idle
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 idle3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 idle3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 pydoc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 pydoc3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 pydoc3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 python-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 python3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 python3-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 python3.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 python3.7-gdb.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 python3.7m
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 python3.7m-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 pyvenv
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff  415 May  4 23:59 pyvenv-3.7

<user>-mbp:python_others <user>$ ls -l /Users/<user>/.pyenv/version
-rw-r--r--  1 <user>  staff  6 May  6 17:54 /Users/<user>/.pyenv/version

<user>-mbp:python_others <user>$ cat /Users/<user>/.pyenv/version
3.7.7

<user>-mbp:python_others <user>$ ls -l /Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  6 <user>  staff  192 May  4 23:59 3.7.7

<user>-mbp:python_others <user>$ ls -l /Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  24 <user>  staff  768 May  7 18:45 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 <user>  staff   96 May  4 23:59 include
drwxr-xr-x   5 <user>  staff  160 May  6 17:53 lib
drwxr-xr-x   3 <user>  staff   96 May  4 23:59 share

<user>-mbp:python_others <user>$ ls -l /Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/bin/
total 13144
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff        8 May  6 17:53 2to3 -> 2to3-3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff      125 May  6 17:53 2to3-3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff       16 May  4 23:59 easy_install -> easy_install-3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff      265 May  4 23:59 easy_install-3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff        7 May  4 23:59 idle -> idle3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff        7 May  6 17:53 idle3 -> idle3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff      123 May  6 17:53 idle3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff        8 May  4 23:59 pydoc -> pydoc3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff        8 May  6 17:53 pydoc3 -> pydoc3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff      108 May  6 17:53 pydoc3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff        9 May  4 23:59 python -> python3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff       16 May  4 23:59 python-config -> python3.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff        9 May  6 17:53 python3 -> python3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff       16 May  6 17:53 python3-config -> python3.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 <user>  staff  3315736 May  6 17:53 python3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff       17 May  6 17:53 python3.7-config -> python3.7m-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff    65363 May  6 17:53 python3.7-gdb.py
-rwxr-xr-x  2 <user>  staff  3315736 May  6 17:53 python3.7m
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff     1959 May  6 17:53 python3.7m-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff       10 May  6 17:53 pyvenv -> pyvenv-3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff      465 May  6 17:53 pyvenv-3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  staff      237 May  7 18:22 wheel
```

Is it still ok to have pip in /Users//.local/bin ?

Do I have to move into pyenv environment ?

If I have to move , how I can move ?